# How to delimit letters and numbers from a string in an array in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I need to delimit the letters and the numbers from a string in an array in Python.

My array is this one:

```
kid_count_list = ['Sofia 1', 'Claire Ann 1', 'Joe 3', 'Betty 2', 'Archie 1', 'Phil 1', 'Luke 1']
```

And I want to make two arrays like these:

```
names = ['Sofia', 'Claire Ann', 'Joe', 'Betty', 'Archie', 'Phil', 'Luke']
counts = [1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

My approach is this one (being inspired from other questions):

```
import re

kid_count_list = ['Sofia 1', 'Claire Ann 1', 'Joe 3', 'Betty 2', 'Archie 1', 'Phil 1', 'Luke 1']
names = []
count = []

for element in kid_count_list:
    name = " ".join(re.split("[^a-zA-Z]*", element))
    occurence = int(element.match('/\d+/g').join(""))
    names.append(name)
    counts.append(occurence)
```

How to make this work? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `'/\d+/g'` is wrong regex syntax, you need `.str.findall(r'\d+')`

Comment: Thank you, but how exactly could it be repaired/ where to put this new syntax ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: "How to make this work?" Well, what happens when you try your code? How is that different from what you want to happen? When you go through it step by step, what parts of it behave differently from your expectation?

Comment: You removed the pandas and numpy dependencies from the question? So is it not related to Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```py
names, counts = zip(*[re.fullmatch(r"(\D+)\s(\d+)", s).groups() for s in kid_count_list])
```

to get the `names` as

```
('Sofia', 'Claire Ann', 'Joe', 'Betty', 'Archie', 'Phil', 'Luke')
```

and `counts` as

```
('1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1')
```

They are not lists, but can be easily cast so:

```
names = list(names)
counts = list(map(int, counts))  # convert the counts to int, too
```

to get

```
>>> names
['Sofia', 'Claire Ann', 'Joe', 'Betty', 'Archie', 'Phil', 'Luke']

>>> counts
[1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

We form a regex to match some non-digits `(\D+)` and a space after it `\s` and some digits at the end `(\d+)`; and we require this to be a full match i.e. from beginning to end (same as if there were `^` and `$` anchors). Then take out the matched groups for each string. At this point we have:

```
[('Sofia', '1'), ('Claire Ann', '1'), ('Joe', '3'), ('Betty', '2'), ('Archie', '1'), ('Phil', '1'), ('Luke', '1')]
```

To take out two lists from this, we use `zip(*...)` construct.

Answer (score 1):

**If no Pandas is in use**, you can use

```py
import re
kid_count_list = ['Sofia 1', 'Claire Ann 1', 'Joe 3', 'Betty 2', 'Archie 1', 'Phil 1', 'Luke 1']
rx = re.compile(r'\s+(?=\d+$)')
l = [rx.split(x) for x in kid_count_list]
names, counts = zip(*l)
print(list(names))  # => ['Sofia', 'Claire Ann', 'Joe', 'Betty', 'Archie', 'Phil', 'Luke']
print(list(counts)) # => ['1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/60umqS) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/11ArsP/1).

Here, `re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+$)', x)` will split each string with any one or more whitespace chars that are followed with one or more digits at the end of string.

*Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\d+$)` - a positive lookahead that assures there are one or more digits at the end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

**Since originally your question contained references to Pandas, here is a Pandas version**

You can use

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

kid_count_list = ['Sofia 1', 'Claire Ann 1', 'Joe 3', 'Betty 2', 'Archie 1', 'Phil 1', 'Luke 1']
cols = [re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+$)', x) for x in kid_count_list]
df = pd.DataFrame(cols, columns=['names', 'counts'])
## >>> df
##         names counts
## 0       Sofia      1
## 1  Claire Ann      1
## 2         Joe      3
## 3       Betty      2
## 4      Archie      1
## 5        Phil      1
## 6        Luke      1
```

**Alternatively, you can use a no-regex solution**:

```py
kid_count_list = ['Sofia 1', 'Claire Ann 1', 'Joe 3', 'Betty 2', 'Archie 1', 'Phil 1', 'Luke 1']
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':kid_count_list})
df[['names', 'counts']] = df.pop('data').str.rsplit(r' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Here, you just initialize the dataframe with `kid_count_list` values, then the `.pop('data')` part will remove the initial column from the dataframe and return it for processing and then it will right-split each value with a space only once.

Comment: @AndrewTulip I added another way, with `rsplit`. No regex needed

Comment: @AndrewTulip I added and explained my regex solution without use of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
import re

kid_count_list = ['Sofia 1', 'Claire Ann 1', 'Joe 3', 'Betty 2', 'Archie 1', 'Phil 1', 'Luke 1']
names, counts = [], []

split_list = [re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+$)', item) for item in kid_count_list]

for item in split_list:
   names.append(item[0])
   counts.append(int(item[1]))
print(names)
print(counts)
```

The output will be

```
['Sofia', 'Claire Ann', 'Joe', 'Betty', 'Archie', 'Phil', 'Luke']
[1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: You are using my regex solution BTW.